# Refreshing Google Analytics API data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've created a dashboard of Google Analytics data that pulls in conversion rate, visits etc and also I have a connection to Magento Api that pulls in sales data.
This is all great but I want all of the Api calls to be refreshed every 10minutes say.

I have one big class with all the Analytics Api calls, and then the functions within this class are called on an index.php page

How do I go about refreshing the data or the page using Ajax as I don't want the page to actually reload?
I've tried using a simple setInternal() that uses .load() to refresh the main div that is wrapped around everything but I don't think this is the correct way to do it.

I'm unsure of what i have to do but I feel like I need to refresh the Api calls and then each div that is echoing out the data
Correct me if I'm wrong as I'm quite new to Ajax

Thanks
Adi

Comment: I think this is more a question exclusively for javascript/ajax.  But I stumbled upon it